# Detecting Control Shift and W

Tags: c#, keypress

i can detect control and w using

```
 if (Keys.W == (Keys)vkCode &&
     Keys.Control == Control.ModifierKeys)
```

However it doesnt seem to be the case that it detects correctly when adding

```
 if (Keys.W == (Keys)vkCode &&
     Keys.Control == Control.ModifierKeys &&
     Keys.Shift= Control.ModifierKeys)
```

Is there anything in particular i need to do to check for 3 keys being pressed opposed to 2?

Comment: The extra bit looks like a very bad typo. Did you mean `Keys.Shift ==` rather than `Keys.Control =`?

Comment: sorry i tried to bold the last && to emphasize the bit i added, all i did was make it worse :/ sorry

Comment: In this situations the best way is to to a MessageBox.Show(e.KeyChar.toString()); inside the KeyPress Event ,than you can pres these combinations and see what is outputting ,im not sure but it will Display an Integer Code .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `ModifierKeys` property is a bitmask, so you need to do a bitwise OR on both the `Control` and `Shift` values.

```
 if (Keys.W == (Keys)vkCode &&
     (Keys.Control | Keys.Shift) == Control.ModifierKeys)
```